# How do I include photos in blender?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, photorealism

Suppose I want to make a photoframe and I want to show a photo in that, How should I do this to avoid any stretching or cropping of photo?
I have tried using a plane ( UV unwrap it ) and add image texture over it but sometimes it produces stretched photos or cropped photos, How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to *File, User Preferences*, then under *Addons* search for **Planes** and enable *Import Images as planes*, then simply do *File, Import,* and choose *images as planes*. Select the Image you want to import and viola, it will be imported perfectly scaled and UV mapped automatically.